# converting the coordinates of a 300 dpi image to coordinates of a 72 dpi image

Tags: coordinates, image-resizing, tesseract, dpi

I'm working on a tess4J project and using tess4j, i've gotten the coordinates of words in the image. The only problem is, these are coordinates for a TIFF image. My project involves writing a layer of text  overr the image in a pdf document. I take it the resolution of a pdf document is 72dpi. So the coordinates are morphed and too widely placed. If i can bring down the resolution from 300 dpi to 72dpi and THEN pass the image to tessaract,  wont i get the coordinates i need? If not, any alternatives? already tried multiplying the coordinates with 300/72. Surprisingly, that doesnt work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just map the coordinates form the 72dpi to the 300dpi space (just multiply them by 72/300) ?

Comment: No tried that... Besides i need to map the coordinates from a 300 dpi to 72 dpi space. I already tried multiplying the x and y coordinates with 300/72. Not working.

Comment: Your assumption that a PDF is always 72 dpi may be incorrect.

Comment: But isnt that the adobe specification?

Comment: how do i find out the dpi of a ODF then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert from 300DPI to 72DPI, you need to multiply by 72/300, not the other way round. Do it in floating point or the multiplication first and division then, as in (x * 72) / 300. PDF units are always 1/72 of an inch.

Scaling down the original image is not a good idea, since the loss of information will reduce the output text quality.

Answer (score 0):

`-(UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize`

{

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);`

`[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];`

`UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();`

`UIGraphicsEndImageContext();`

`NSLog(@"New image has w=%f, h=%f", newImage.size.width, newImage.size.height);`

return newImage;

}

this code to change any image  72 dpi.